# Fluent NHibernate / NHibernate via NuGet for SQL2012

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, sql-server-2012

I've just installed the following latest packages from NuGet:

FluentNHibernate.1.3.0.733
NHibernate.3.3.2.4000 (was required for FNH)

I'm trying to get our ASP.NET MVC 3 app running using SQL 2012 (native).

The following code is taken from our method which builds our nhibernate Session:

```
    var sqlConfig = MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2005.ConnectionString(ConnectionString).AdoNetBatchSize(30);
```

We also use this approach for provisioning a new emtpy DB using the code first approach.

I need to use the SQL 2012 dialiect but neither the latest FNH or NHibernate have it from NuGet.

Does anyone kow the status of the code in Git for these? I can see  a merge for FNH for this 2012 dialiect was done 7 months ago (a month after the latest NuGet was released).

What are others doing to connect to SQL 2012?

Does anyone know when the next NuGet packagaes for these will be available?

Comment: Please don't include "Thanks in advance" in your question. It is useless noise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the SQL Server 2008 dialect. I don't know of any changes in 2012 that would require an update to the dialect.

Comment: There are very important changes! Sequence support and proper limits syntax, among others.

Comment: I have a hard time imagining a use case for sequence. By limits do you mean the new paging syntax? My point, which I could have stated better, is that the 2008 syntax will work with 2012 in most cases.

Comment: Sequences are used for Hilo, and work better than tables for that. 2008 syntax works with 2012, but the new one is more efficient.

Comment: Thanks - I'm now using MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008 and works fine. I'm still a little concerned though. Does anyone know when the latest version will be shipped via NuGet?

Answer (score 3):

It's already supported by the NHibernate core, so it's just a matter of using `MsSql2012Dialect`:

```
var sqlConfig = MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2005.Dialect<MsSql2012Dialect>();
```

`MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2012` was [added](https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/commit/326bec31e2498b7f5c28b9431a40176314ee4ac4) to Fluent shortly after the latest release, so you can grab the source if you want, but the end result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

My current setup is using NHibernate (3.3.2.4000) and FluentNHibernate (1.3.0.733) and the first part of my connection setup looks like this, feel free to adapt it to your needs. Note that even though I pull the connection string using the `MsSql2008` configuration class, I have set my dialect to `MsSql2012Dialect`

```
var cfg = Fluent.NHibernate.Cfg.Fluently.Configure()
    .Database(FluentNHibernate.Cfg.Db.MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008
             .ConnectionString(c => c.FromConnectionStringWithKey("KeyName"))
        #if DEBUG
        .ShowSql()
        .FormatSql()
        #endif
        .Dialect<NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2012Dialect>()
        .AdoNetBatchSize(50)
    )
    //Other chained methods (for setting up cache, mappings, etc)
    //.Mappings(m =>
    //{
    //
    //}

var sessionFactory = cfg.BuildSessionFactory();
```

from what I can see the 2012 Dialect just adds support for `Sequences` and registers `iif` as a function.